# My Electorate badge doesn't appear!

Tags: support, badges

I have voted on over 600 questions, with 25% or more of them being on questions(or whatever that means). I have waited for approximately an hour, and I still haven't received the badge. What's wrong?

Comment: nevermind. I literally JUST received the badge.

Comment: Some of the harder-to-obtain badges don't kick in straight away, I'm guessing because the scripts that check if it should be awarded are only run a few times a day.

Comment: This recent question mentions the badge script: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7888/when-is-mortarboard-awarded